# How can I add words from text file into arraylist in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a wordlist as below. I want to add these words to the arraylist line by line. I tried this but didn't work.

```
acaba
altı
altmış
ama
ancak
arada
artık
asla
aslında
```

My code is below;

```
String path = @"C:\Users\.......\xxx.txt";
String readpath = File.ReadAllText(path);

ArrayList wordList = new ArrayList();

wordList.Add(readpath);
```

Comment: Maybe you want `File.ReadAllLines()` and just use the array it returns. Why would you need an ArrayList?

Comment: After I add these words then I'm going to remove matching words from another text file. So that I think that it has to be an ArrayList am I right?

Comment: No, why? You can use `string[]` arrays. See LINQ's `Except()` method, for example. ArrayList is a very old collection type, you use a generic `IEnumerable<T>` / `List<T>` most of the time. You just need the array here.

Comment: Ok I understand what you are suggesting. I used string[] array and just add ToArray() at the end like; String[] readpath = File.ReadAllText(path).ToArray(); and it worked thank you :)

Comment: `String[] readpath = File.ReadAllLines(path);`

Comment: Sorry I wrote wrong yes that was the answer :)

Comment: Never use an ArrayList. It became obsolete more than 10 years ago when List<> was introduced, which is more performant and safer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using `File.ReadAllLines()` which returns an array of strings and then pass it into the `ArrayList` constructor

```
String path = @"C:\Users\.......\xxx.txt";
String[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);

ArrayList list = new ArrayList(lines);
```

Comment: This isn’t really an improvement. If anything it makes the code worse, because you go from a type-safe array to a type-unsafe ArrayList.

Comment: I answered the question regarding how to create an arraylist from reading the file line by line line, not about the disadvantages of the chosen data structure because it wasn't the question